# update column if value matches a different column within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

[image]

And what I want to update the `new_parentID` with the `new_campaignID` field if the `old_campaignID = old_parentID`

Here is an example

```
col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F |
1     | 1     | 4     | a     | 7     | NULL  |
2     | 2     | 5     | b     | 2     | NULL  |
3     | 3     | 6     | c     | 8     | NULL  |
```

So if col b = col E I want to populate col f on the same row of col e

result

```
col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F |
2     | 2     | 5     | b     | 2     | 5     |
```

I tried:

```
update test1 
set new_campaignID = new_parentID 
where old_campaignID = old_ParentID;
```

but it didn't work

Comment: "same table" or "same row"?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Could you show some examples of the updates you want? And post the table as text, not image, so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: @Uueerdo same table just need to populate "new_parentID" column if the two "old" columns match. thanks!

Comment: @Barmar sure give me a moment appreciate the help

Comment: Then what's the problem? `WHERE old_campaignID = old_parentID` in your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: You basically just translate the sentence you wrote in the question into SQL syntax.

Comment: @Barmar I tried:
update test1
set new_campaignID = new_parentID
where old_campaignID = old_ParentID;
but it didn't work

Comment: Your assignment is backwards, it should be `set new_parentID = new_campaignID`

Comment: @DavidO if that relatively simple UPDATE works, "same row" would've been more accurate; "same table" would indicate something like Gordon's answer.

Comment: @Uueerdo sorry for the noob mistake!

Comment: @DavidO no prob; mainly just clarifying the difference for future ref.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join`.  I think the query you want is:

```
update test1 t1 join
       test1 tt1
       on t.old_campaignId = tt1.old_parentId
    set t1.new_campaignID = tt1.new_parentID ;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks yes I needed a join but its 90% there the problem is its working on the null value rows and if I use an "AND A.old_ParentID IS NOT NULL" the update fails. here's my join:  

update test1 AS A, test1 AS B  
set A.new_parentID = B.new_campaignID  
where B.old_campaignID = A.old_ParentID;  

Thanks! - sorry I can't figure out this formatting....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for your

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
   colA CHAR(1),
   colB CHAR(1),
   colC CHAR(1),
   colD CHAR(1),
   colE CHAR(1),
   colF CHAR(1)
);

/*col A | col B | col C | col D | col E | col F |
1     | 1     | 4     | a     | 7     | NULL  |
2     | 2     | 5     | b     | 2     | NULL  |
3     | 3     | 6     | c     | 8     | NULL  |*/

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
('1','1','4','a','7',null),
('2','2','5','b','2',null),
('3','3','6','c','8',null);
```

You can use `SET` to populate the column

```
UPDATE T1
SET colF = colE
WHERE colB = colE;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86890)